Spring Security: Login page keeps redirecting to itself
i'm basically a beginner when it comes to spring security and i'm trying to apply a certain filter that would help me check for the device fingerprint on any request that would require authentication, but the problem is the /login page that is default to spring security keeps redirecting to itself when i try to request a url that does need authentication (/api/auth/authtest), here's my FilterChain:

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.Customizer;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.AbstractHttpConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Value("${authentication-test.auth.tokenSecret}")
    private String jwtSecret;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("FilterChain Called********************************");
        http
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
                        .requestMatchers("/login", "/api/auth/signin", "/api/auth/test", "/swagger-ui/index.html", "/actuator/health").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated())
                .formLogin(form -> form.loginPage("/login").permitAll())
                .addFilterAfter(deviceFingerprintFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        return http.build();
    }


    public DeviceFingerprintFilter deviceFingerprintFilter() {
        return new DeviceFingerprintFilter(jwtSecret);
    }

    public RateLimitingFilter rateLimitingFilter() {
        return new RateLimitingFilter();
    }
}

And here's my DeviceFingerprintFilter

import io.jsonwebtoken.Claims;
import io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts;
import io.jsonwebtoken.SignatureException;
import jakarta.servlet.FilterChain;
import jakarta.servlet.ServletException;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.Base64;

public class DeviceFingerprintFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private final String jwtSecret;

    public DeviceFingerprintFilter(String jwtSecret) {
        this.jwtSecret = jwtSecret;
    }

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // Check if the user is authenticated
        if (SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().isAuthenticated() && !isExcludedUri(request.getRequestURI())) {

            System.out.println("++++++++++++++++>>>>>>>>>>>>>> " + request.getRequestURI());
            String token = extractJwtFromRequest(request);

            if (token != null) {
                try {
                    // Configure a JWT parser to verify the token and retrieve the claims
                    Claims claims = Jwts.parser()
                            .setSigningKey(jwtSecret.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
                            .build()
                            .parseClaimsJws(token.replace("Bearer ", ""))
                            .getBody();

                    String deviceFingerprintFromToken = claims.get("User-Fingerprint", String.class);

                    String currentUserAgent = request.getHeader("User-Agent");
                    String currentIpAddr = request.getRemoteAddr();
                    String currentDeviceFingerprint = hashDeviceFingerprint(currentUserAgent, currentIpAddr);

                    if (deviceFingerprintFromToken.equals(currentDeviceFingerprint)) {
                        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
                    } else {
                        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Invalid device fingerprint");
                    }

                } catch (SignatureException e) {
                    response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Invalid token");
                }
            } else {
                response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Missing token");
            }
        } else {
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    }

    private String extractJwtFromRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String bearerToken = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        if (bearerToken != null && bearerToken.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            return bearerToken.substring(7); 
        }
        return null;
    }

    private String hashDeviceFingerprint(String userAgent, String ipAddr) {
        try {
            String input = userAgent + ipAddr;
            MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
            byte[] hashBytes = digest.digest(input.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(hashBytes);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("SHA-256 algorithm not available", e);
        }
    }
    private boolean isExcludedUri(String uri) {
        return uri.equals("/login") || uri.equals("/api/auth/signin") || uri.equals("/api/auth/test") ||
                uri.equals("/swagger-ui/index.html") || uri.equals("/actuator/health");
    }
}

As for the logs:
2024-07-02T15:40:41.149+01:00 DEBUG 50451 --- [auth-service] [nio-8038-exec-2] [66841169cd8b5e73217e0a96d17bbc0b-c778a75b31b38210] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
2024-07-02T15:40:41.345+01:00 DEBUG 50451 --- [auth-service] [nio-8038-exec-2] [66841169cd8b5e73217e0a96d17bbc0b-ed7fee28a1de34ad] o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache        : Saved request http://localhost:8038/api/auth/authtest?continue to session
2024-07-02T15:40:41.352+01:00 DEBUG 50451 --- [auth-service] [nio-8038-exec-2] [66841169cd8b5e73217e0a96d17bbc0b-ed7fee28a1de34ad] o.s.s.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy        : Redirecting to http://localhost:8038/login
2024-07-02T15:40:42.226+01:00 DEBUG 50451 --- [auth-service] [nio-8038-exec-1] [6684116a9fd6e7a3b8de6edb097b2e94-b8de6edb097b2e94] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /login
2024-07-02T15:40:42.229+01:00 DEBUG 50451 --- [auth-service] [nio-8038-exec-1] [6684116a9fd6e7a3b8de6edb097b2e94-1813bead978a410c] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured GET /login
2024-07-02T15:40:42.266+01:00 DEBUG 50451 --- [auth-service] [nio-8038-exec-1] [6684116a9fd6e7a3b8de6edb097b2e94-1813bead978a410c] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
2024-07-02T15:40:42.297+01:00 DEBUG 50451 --- [auth-service] [nio-8038-exec-1] [                                                 ] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /error
2024-07-02T15:40:42.303+01:00 DEBUG 50451 --- [auth-service] [nio-8038-exec-1] [6684116aa74ddbdc29f7ea4a027df018-caf5568c75153840] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
2024-07-02T15:40:42.324+01:00 DEBUG 50451 --- [auth-service] [nio-8038-exec-1] [6684116aa74ddbdc29f7ea4a027df018-29f7ea4a027df018] o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache        : Saved request http://localhost:8038/error?continue to session
2024-07-02T15:40:42.325+01:00 DEBUG 50451 --- [auth-service] [nio-8038-exec-1] [6684116aa74ddbdc29f7ea4a027df018-29f7ea4a027df018] o.s.s.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy        : Redirecting to http://localhost:8038/login
2024-07-02T15:40:42.486+01:00 DEBUG 50451 --- [auth-service] [nio-8038-exec-5] [6684116a2166c682a42e072ad69210f0-a42e072ad69210f0] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /login
2024-07-02T15:40:42.488+01:00 DEBUG 50451 --- [auth-service] [nio-8038-exec-5] [6684116a2166c682a42e072ad69210f0-755d44307f186095] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured GET /login
2024-07-02T15:40:42.491+01:00 DEBUG 50451 --- [auth-service] [nio-8038-exec-5] [6684116a2166c682a42e072ad69210f0-755d44307f186095] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
2024-07-02T15:40:42.494+01:00 DEBUG 50451 --- [auth-service] [nio-8038-exec-5] [                                                 ] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /error
2024-07-02T15:40:42.496+01:00 DEBUG 50451 --- [auth-service] [nio-8038-exec-5] [6684116aff72acdebb99affb35222cf7-ba7d02d4d411bd7b] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
2024-07-02T15:40:42.498+01:00 DEBUG 50451 --- [auth-service] [nio-8038-exec-5] [6684116aff72acdebb99affb35222cf7-bb99affb35222cf7] o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache        : Saved request http://localhost:8038/error?continue to session
2024-07-02T15:40:42.498+01:00 DEBUG 50451 --- [auth-service] [nio-8038-exec-5] [6684116aff72acdebb99affb35222cf7-bb99affb35222cf7] o.s.s.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy        : Redirecting to http://localhost:8038/login
2024-07-02T15:40:42.516+01:00 DEBUG 50451 --- [auth-service] [nio-8038-exec-4] [6684116a0b023ef587157ade80985c86-87157ade80985c86] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /login

And it keeps on looping until i get an error that tells me that localhost redirected me too many times
I even tried to explicity check on said pages before but with no avail, any help would be much appreciated

what is the url (exact url please) that you tried calling and what was the response and what were the server logs? (set logging level to debug with logging.level.org.springframework.security=DEBUG so that you see the error in server logs). Please add all the things I asked for into the question (not in comments)

please explain why you are not using the built in jwt features of spring security and customize them to your needs?
